# How to get a commit SHA from a release or tag on Github API V3

Tags: github, github-api

The release nor tag response don't seem to have information (SHA) about the commit they were made from. How can I get it if I only have a tag/release like `v1.2.3`?

Comment: There's no specific api to get commit sha from tag name. You can use the list tags api, iterate over the response and get the desired tag details with commit sha. More on it here https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-tags

Comment: @MadhuBhat do you want to move this to a proper answer? ... it makes sense, thanks :)

Comment: Sure @Ondrej :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no specific endpoint in GitHub API v3 to get the commit SHA from tag/release name.

For your use-case, you can use the [List tags](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-repository-tags) endpoint to get all the tags for a particular repo, iterate over the response and get the desired tag details with the commit SHA.

Endpoint: `GET /repos/:owner/:repo/tags`

Sample response below:

```
[
  {
    "name": "v0.1",
    "commit": {
      "sha": "c5b97d5ae6c19d5c5df71a34c7fbeeda2479ccbc",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/commits/c5b97d5ae6c19d5c5df71a34c7fbeeda2479ccbc"
    },
    "zipball_url": "https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World/zipball/v0.1",
    "tarball_url": "https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World/tarball/v0.1"
  }
]
```